# How to check my current location against locations in a remote file - iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, gps

I have a simple locations map and I want to make my app beep when the user is approaching a location that is listed in a remote file

the listed locations are on my server named locations.txt

how can i check locations.txt every 1 minute to see if the user is within 300m of a location??

Comment: You might want to consider using [Monitoring Shape-Based Regions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13) discussed in the _Location Awareness Programming Guide_ instead. Slightly different approach, but achieves what you want functionally, perhaps with more efficient battery use.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I am new to this type of programming and am unsure how to use this to check the locations.txt. I read that it doesnt handle many locations at once? needs to be able to handle around 90 locations

Comment: So you will cache that file locally on the device. You can update it from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard answer to this question is [Shape-Based Regions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13) as described in the *Location Awareness Guide.* Generally, shape-based regions is the way to go if you have a limited number of regions. But, given that you want a lot of regions, you might have to "roll your own":

- Turn on a location service and monitor your location. See the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1). If you use standard location service, make sure to set a `desiredAccuracy` that is as low as possible to achieve the functional need (e.g. `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters`).
- Once you've successfully received the first [`didUpdateLocations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a), if you really want to check every minute, you could create a timer at that point. If the purpose of that timer is to just check the users' location, then the timer is really not needed and you can just wait for occurrences of the `didUpdateLocations`.
- You can iterate through your array of locations to monitor (I'd convert them to `CLLocation` objects) and simply use [`distanceFromLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a).

A couple of observations, though:

- You suggest that you want to check `locations.txt` every minute to see if user is within 300m of location. I can imagine two reasons why you might have proposed that solution:

  - *Did server's `locations.txt` change?* If this is the problem you're trying to solve, a better solution would be [push notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW7) (a.k.a. "remote notifications") and you want to make sure the client has access to the latest information. The process of constantly re-retrieving the file is very expensive (in terms of bandwidth, battery, computationally); or
  - *Did the user move?* If you're concerned about whether the user may have moved, the right solution is not to check every minute, but rather wait for the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`] instance method [`didUpdateLocations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a) to be called. If you want to avoid too many redundant checks, you can always keep track of whether the last request took place less than a minute ago or not, and then only check again if it was more than a minute ago. But that's very different than checking every minute whether you need to or not.
- You've suggested using a text file. You might want to contemplate using a JSON file (or XML file), which is a better mechanism for retrieving data from a server.

---

For example, if you have a text file in JSON format, you can parse the results in another single line of code ([`JSONObjectWithData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData%3aoptions%3aerror%3a)). To illustrate, let me show you what a JSON file might look like (where the square brackets designate an array, and the curly braces designate a dictionary, this is therefore an array of dictionaries):

```
[
  {
    "name" : "Battery Park",
    "latitude" : 40.702,
    "longitude" : -74.015
  },
  {
    "name" : "Grand Central Station",
    "latitude" : 40.753,
    "longitude" : -73.977
  }
]
```

Then your app can retrieve the results incredibly easily with two lines:

```
NSData *locationsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSArray *locationsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:locationsData options:0 error:&error];
```

So, you'll need to start location services:

```
if (nil == self.locationManager)
   self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

// Set a movement threshold for new events.
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 500;

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

You'll then have a routine for checking the current location:

```
- (void)checkLocation
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kLocationsUrlString];
    NSData *locationsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSAssert(locationsData, @"failure to download data"); // replace this with graceful error handling

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *locationsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:locationsData
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:&error];
    NSAssert(locationsArray, @"failure to parse JSON");   // replace with with graceful error handling

    for (NSDictionary *locationEntry in locationsArray)
    {
        NSNumber *longitude = locationEntry[@"longitude"];
        NSNumber *latitude = locationEntry[@"latitude"];
        NSString *locationName = locationEntry[@"name"];

        CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude doubleValue]
                                                          longitude:[longitude doubleValue]];
        NSAssert(location, @"failure to create location");

        CLLocationDistance distance = [location distanceFromLocation:self.locationManager.location];

        if (distance <= 300)
        {
            NSLog(@"You are within 300 meters (actually %.0f meters) of %@", distance, locationName);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"You are not within 300 meters (actually %.0f meters) of %@", distance, locationName);
        }
    }
}
```

And this will be called when the user's location changes:

```
// this is used in iOS 6 and later

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [self checkLocation];
}

// this is used in iOS 5 and earlier

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 6.0)
        [self checkLocation];
}
```

The implementation might look like [this test project on GitHub](https://github.com/robertmryan/ios-location-test). This is a barebones implementation, but it gives you an idea of the tools you have at hand, namely retrieving your `locations.json` file and comparing that to the location retrieved by the device.

Comment: Sorry im a little unsure on how to do this, so far i have  `{

    NSArray *locationsArray; 
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *locationsArray;`  and `@synthesize locationsArray;`  I'm not sure how this changes it to check a cached file and not try to download it each time it checks the locations??

Comment: ok if i just use the @property line i then need to replace all locationsArray with self.locationsArray correct?  Just wondering if you could also help me with this code for android platform?

Comment: ok thanx.  My next question is how to play a beep sound when the user is within the 300m of location? Would this [link here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/259/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-playing-audio-programmatically) be pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: ok i keep getting 3 errors with this..  `NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                pathForResource:@"beep-5" ofType:@"wav"];
        NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];`  then when it plays the sound `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(soundURL), &_Sound);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_Sound);
            NSLog(@"You are not within 250 meters (actually %.0f meters) of %@", distance, locationName);`

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[ViewController checkLocation] in ViewController.o
  "_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
      -[ViewController checkLocation] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @KristanHalls 1. If you ever get that sort of error, look up the method or class in the documentation and figure out what framework it is in (in this case, `AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h`). So, [add that framework to your project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html). 2. No offense, but your questions are starting to really drift from this original question, so rather than posting comments to this answer, you really should be posting new questions (and always search for existing answers before posting new questions).

Comment: thanx got that working now to. My original question actually says "I want to make my app beep when the user is approaching a location that is listed in a remote file" so currently we are back on the right track of doing that. But i got it sorted now :)

Comment: how would i call this checkLocation from a button?

Comment: @KristanHalls No offense, but I'm taken aback by that question. I can't believe you don't know how to link some code to a button because that's part of practically any iOS tutorial. And I can't believe you don't know how to make the code for that button call another method, `checkLocation`. Maybe I'm not understanding the question.